# Android viewpage run wrong tab

Tags: android-fragments

If I click second Tab, It run `onCreateView()` method of third Tab. I don't want to run third Tab. Because it seems Toast in third Tab. It is unnecessary.

I have `FragmentActivity` called `TestActivity`.

FragmentActivity :

```
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private ViewPager _mViewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter _adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    setUpView();
    setTab();
}

    private void setUpView(){
        _mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        _adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(_mViewPager.getContext(),getSupportFragmentManager());
        _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
        _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        _mViewPager.destroyDrawingCache();
        _mViewPager.clearAnimation();
}
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter class:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Context _context;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    _context=context;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment f = new Fragment();
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            f= Test1Activity.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        case 1:
            f= Test2Activity.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        case 2:
            f= Test3Activity.newInstance(_context);
            break;
    }
    return f;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}}
```

Test1Activity class :

```
public class Test1Activity extends Fragment {
public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    Test1Activity f = new Test1Activity();
    return f;
}

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpage_test1, null);
    root.destroyDrawingCache();
    root.clearAnimation();
}}
```

So If I click `Test1Activity`in Tab Fragment, It works `onCreateView()` method of Test2Activity. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: place your toast code in onResume(), may this solve your problem

Comment: It doesn't matter about Toast. I have many code blocks.